# How can I exclude application.properties from fat JAR using Maven?

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I try to build a `Spring Boot` project, using Maven (latest versions). It makes no sense to include my dev settings in a JAR that is aimed to be deployed in production.

The question is: **How can I exclude application.properties from the resulting fat JAR?**

If there are better approaches to this problem, feel free to give some hints.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <!-- Exclude application.properties (?) -->
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could configure an exclusions of [parts of your resources like this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html):

```
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>*-dev*.properties</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
```

you need to customize the excludes depending on your requirements.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!